# What this abbr and acronym selectors address?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking source code for one of the `Zen garden` projects and I found selectors which I haven't seen before:

```
abbr[title],
acronym[title] {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

What they trying to address? What the purpose of them?

Comment: These selectors aren't any different from, say, `p[title]` or `h1[title]` or `body[title]`. The `[title]` portion means "elements with a title attribute". Unless your question, judging by the accepted answer, is really "what are the abbr and acronym elements?" in which case this is a question about HTML, not CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The html elements:

**abbr**:

> The HTML Abbreviation element () represents an abbreviation and
>   optionally provides a full description for it. If present, the title
>   attribute must contain this full description and nothing else.

```css
abbr[title] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>I do <abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr>
</p>
```

**acronym**

> The HTML Acronym Element () allows authors to clearly
>   indicate a sequence of characters that compose an acronym or
>   abbreviation for a word.
>
> **Obsolete** This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any
>   time. Try to avoid using it.

```css
acronym[title] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>The <acronym title="World Wide Web">WWW</acronym> is only one component of the Internet.</p>
```

**References**:

[acronym](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/acronym)

[abbr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr)

Comment: @NikitaLuparev you are welcome. Don't forget to check references too. If this answer addresses your OP please mark it as correct.

Comment: it's correct I just have to wait 8 minutes before I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here the solution](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_abbr.asp)

Very simple, target the title of abbr tag :)